# How to prevent my computer from connecting to a specific site

Tags: networking, hosts

I recently decided to make the switch to Ubuntu. And I had a question pertaining to site connections. Before beginning, I need to give some context. I am/was addicted to youtube. I think at my peak in my teen years I spent around 6 hours a day watching youtube. And so I decided to change that by making it impossible for my computer to connect to youtube.com. This was as simple as going into the windows 32 hosts files and plugging in the url of the site you don't want to connect to. It worked great and I've been much more productive.

I was curious if Linux Ubuntu had a similar functionality.

Comment: I don't know the technical solution to your problem, but I personally think it wouldn't work because you will end up knowing how to bypass this restriction.  If you think you have an "addiction" and you want to do something about it, maybe seeking professional help would be better?  Just a suggestion...  But yes, I agree...YouTube is very addictive!

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/147653/redirect-domain-name-to-localhost

Comment: If you are using a desktop at home. you can block through your router. The router admin GUI will be easy to navigate to input the block.

Comment: Public service announcement: the StackExchange network of sites, and thus AskUbuntu within it, was designed to be **highly addictive**. Be warned.

Answer (score 0):

Please do:

```
sudo -i
echo "0.0.0.0 youtube.com"  >>  /etc/hosts
exit
```

This may be, as has been mentioned in the comments, ineffective as anyhing we may do may later be undone.